# Count Number Of Words In a Textarea

Tags: php, html

I have a text area that gets input from a PHP script, and I would like to count the number of words or line breaks in the textarea and echo it below the text area.

This is what the code looks like for the `textarea`.

```
<textarea name="domains" cols="120" rows="5" style="max-width:100%;">
    <?php $output_array = explode(" ",$output);
    $count = count($output_array);
    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
    echo $output_array[$i]."\n";
    }
    ?>
</textarea><br />
<br>
        <?php
        preg_match_all("/(\n)/", $_POST['domains'], $matches);
         $total_lines = count($matches[0]) + 1;
         echo $total_lines;
        ?>
        <br />
```

I tried using preg_match_all but the output I get is only **"1"**, regardless of how many line breaks are inside the text area.

Comment: _"I can't seem to make it work"_ is a vague description - strive to describe exactly what happens and also include some sample data and your desired result.

Comment: `/\w+/` You can use \w for words and not \n

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'as aa frd sad as
kjhsdf sdkjh 
sd sdkjhsdf
sjkldhfh sdfjh sd';


preg_match_all("/\w+/", $str, $matches);
echo 'Words = ' . count($matches[0]);
echo PHP_EOL;
preg_match_all("/\n/", $str, $matches);
echo 'newlines = ' . count($matches[0]);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'So number of line is = ' . count($matches[0])+1;
```

RESULT

```
Words = 12
newlines = 3
So number of line is = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode(" ", $input) function($item) {
    return !!$item;
});

$count = count($arr) + count(explode("\n", implode(",", $arr)));
```

This splits the string by space, filters out empty items to avoid issues due to multiple spaces found between words, then glues the array back into a string, splits it by newline and adds the two counts together.